# Rails Validation | add class to surrounding <div>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Rails question.  The default behavior for error validation is to fieldWithError-styled div around the input field like the following

```
<div class="type-text" id="pre_negotiation_value_div">
<label for="contract_budget_holder">Budget Holder</label>
<div class="fieldWithErrors">
<input id="contract_budget_holder"name="contract[budget_holder]" size="30" type="text" value="" />
</div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, to surround the label AND the input field with a classed div tag, so to look like the following:

```
<div class="type-text fieldWithErrors" id="pre_negotiation_value_div">
<label for="contract_budget_holder">Budget Holder</label>      
<input id="contract_budget_holder"name="contract[budget_holder]" size="30" type="text" value="" />      
</div>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?  Can you hook up javascript into ActionView::Base.field_error_proc?

I am new to Rails, I apologize if this is super easy!

Thanks for your help.

Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super easy to do exactly what you want, but if you have ERB like this:

```
<div id="pre_negotiation_value_div" class="type-text">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
```

You will get HTML like this:

```
<div id="pre_negotiation_value_div" class="type-text">
  <div class="fieldWithErrors"><label for="foo_name">Name</label></div>
  <div class="fieldWithErrors"><input id="foo_name" name="foo[name]" size="30" type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Where both the label and the text_field will have the fieldWithErrors div around them.  Depending on how you want to style it, that might be good enough.  If it's not good enough, you'll have to do a custom helper like this:

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def labeled_input(method, options={}, &block)
    (options[:class] ||= "") << " fieldWithErrors" if @object.errors.on(method)
    ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.send(:alias_method, :original_error_wrapping, :error_wrapping)
    ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.send(:define_method, :error_wrapping,
      Proc.new {|html_tag, has_error| html_tag})
    @template.concat(@template.content_tag(:div, @template.capture(&block), options))
  ensure
    ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.send(:alias_method, :error_wrapping, :original_error_wrapping)
    ActionView::Helpers::InstanceTag.send(:remove_method, :original_error_wrapping)
  end
end
```

Put that in `config/initializers/labeled_input.rb`.  It's a bunch Ruby meta-foo, but what it does is put the "fieldWithErrors" class on the outer div.  It temporarily re-defines the `error_wrapping` method of `InstanceTag` so that the inner label and text_field tags don't have the "fieldWithErrors" div surrounding them.  You use it in ERB like this:

```
<% f.labeled_input :name, :id => "pre_negotiation_value_div", :class => "type-text" do %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That worked man. Thanks!!  I would have never thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

**RAILS 3 UPDATE**

I'm updating my app to rails 3. If you've used this method and are upgrading you'll get some deprecation warnings and form fields appearing twice or several times.

To fix these:

1) Change the line in labeled_input.rb that checks for errors. This stops deprecation warnings accessing errors:

```
(options[:class] ||= "") << " fieldWithErrors" unless @object.errors[method].empty?
```

2) Change the line in labeled_input.rb before the 'ensure'. This stops form elements appearing multiple times:

```
@template.content_tag(:div, @template.capture(&block), options)
```

3) In your view files where you call labeled_input, use <%= rather than <%. This prevents deprecation warnings.

Hope that saves you some time.